How does Azure's Content-Aware Encoding work?
I was reading Azure's Content-Aware Encoding post here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-content-aware-concept
It says:

In ideal conditions, you want to be aware of the type of content you
are encoding. Using this information you can tune the encoding ladder
to match the complexity and motion in your source video. This means
that at each display size (resolution) in the ladder, there should be
a bitrate beyond which any increase in quality is not perceptive – the
encoder operates at this optimal bitrate value.

How does it compute the video complexity in a fast pass? What exactly do they measure that can represent the video complexity, in an efficient way?
